# How to remove Ubuntu and recover Windows after removing Windows in the first place?

Tags: windows, system-installation

i installed ubuntu from a usb instead of running alongside windows i made it the main os... i now have a laptop with ubuntu on it and i really want windows back on the pc

*ive tired sticking the windows recovery disc in nothing

ive tried booting from recov disc nothing .. is there anyway i could earse everything and start from scratch

my computer is "hp pavilion p6536f-b pc bundle"

Comment: it's not a dupe,the above link shows how to remove ubuntu from a dual-boot system,but the op asked for how to remove ubuntu from a ubuntu only pc and put windows on it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The computer in the question is a single boot, not a dual boot laptop with possibly a Windows recovery partition or possibly not, the question does not inform us either way. The answers to the linked question would answer this question also.

Answer (score 1):

Boot Gparted live disk,and then delete the Ubuntu partition.It will create an unallocated space,create a new ntfs partition from that unallocated space.

Now boot windows installation disk to install windows on the created ntfs partition by selecting the custom option during installation.

**Note**: Before deleting the ubuntu partition,make a backup of important datas.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you want Windows only back:

If you boot with a bootable windows install DVD or USB drive you should get the option to delete the exiting partition (format drive) and install clean/fresh windows.

Of course a format of disk will delete all data on this disk!!

**Edit:** You can download fully legal a Windows 7 SP1 ISO version at http://www.w7forums.com/threads/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads.12325/

make sure you pick the right version for your license and language

Win 8.1 see here http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/18309-windows-8-windows-8-1-iso-download-create.html

Comment: This neglects to mention that a Windows ***Installation*** disk is needed.

Comment: Good point Thomas, 
You can download fully legal a Windows 7 SP1 ISO version at http://www.w7forums.com/threads/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads.12325/  

make sure you pick the right version for your license and language


Win 8.1 see here http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/18309-windows-8-windows-8-1-iso-download-create.html

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and sorry for the initial downvote.  But that of course is kind of a critical missing fact, hence that downvote.  I've removed that and it's an upvote now.  I would also suggest you add a note to your answer (or I'll do it for you) stating that a recovery disk, like the OP tried to use, won't work, since it's not an installation disk.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a windows installation disc to install windows. It cannot be an upgrade disc, or a restore disc, or a recovery disc, or anything but a full installation disc.

You don't need to do anything to ubuntu. All you do is boot from the windows installation disc, and when it asks if you want to overwrite everything, say yes. **You will lose all your data.** If you don't want to **lose all your data**, make a backup first (to say, a usb drive).

Please note, this will not work with anything but an actual full installation disc.